# ¿Porqué guzzle 5.0 lanza el error 422 si estoy armando bien la consulta?

Tags: php, guzzle

El código es, donde $request es https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html:

```
    $clientHttp = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => '192.168.0.7']);

    $arrOpts = [
        'headers' =>[
            'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'body' => $request->input()
    ];

    $requestGuzzle = $clientHttp->createRequest('POST', $request->path(), $arrOpts);

    $responseGuzzle = $clientHttp->send($requestGuzzle);

    //Se transforma el response
    $response = response($responseGuzzle->getBody(), $responseGuzzle->getStatusCode())->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Y el error originado es:

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 89: Client error response
>   [url] http://192.168.0.7/recurso [status code] 422 [reason phrase]
>   Unprocessable Entity

Según entiendo el código 422 es un problema semántico. La verdad he intentado y no consigo ver el error. Intenté con GET y si funciona. Estaré agradecido de cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que no debe ir en la clave body sino en json debido al tipo de request

```
    $clientHttp = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => '192.168.0.7']);
$arrOpts = [
        'headers' =>[
            'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        'json' => $request->input()
    ];

    $requestGuzzle = $clientHttp->createRequest('POST', $request->path(), $arrOpts);

    $responseGuzzle = $clientHttp->send($requestGuzzle);

    //Se transforma el response
    $response = response($responseGuzzle->getBody(), $responseGuzzle->getStatusCode())->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Si lo cambié a json y funcioná, muchas gracias!!!